# Align from middle of div

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly certain this is not your typical "vertical align center" question...
What I'd like to do is take a div of unknown height and position it a certain percentage down the page (say 33%). I have been able to achieve this, but not how I'd like to.

Instead of `postion:absolute; top: 33%` or `bottom:33%;` I'd like to specify the 33% to be calculated from the middle of the div of unknown height. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Javascript to determine the dynamic height of the `div`.

Comment: @siyah: You can do this with Pure css.

Comment: %33 upper from the middle is equal to %17 lower from the top. %33 lower from the middle is equal to %83 lower from top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
.your_div{
  position:absolute;
  top:33%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

In **[this](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem)** codepen, checkout 1st div. I have aligned it in the middle by using `top:50%` you can set it to any percentage.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. Potentially, could also work for any vertical alignment!

Comment: This is useful. I have been doing it with calc and pre-known height/2 up until now.

Comment: Is using display:block cross-browser?

Comment: Yes display:block is crossbroser, but just check for yourself also.